# Pandas read_json : skip first lines of the file

Tags: python, json, pandas

Say I have a json file with lines of data like this :

file.json :

```
{'ID':'098656', 'query':'query_file.txt'}

{'A':1, 'B':2}
{'A':3, 'B':6}
{'A':0, 'B':4}
...
```

where the first line is just explanations about the given file and how it was created.
I would like to open it with something like :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('file.json', lines=True)
```

However, how do I read the data starting on line 3 ? I know that `pd.read_csv` has a `skiprows` argument, but it does not look like `pd.read_json` has one.

I would like something returning a DataFrame with the columns `A` and `B` only, and possibly better than dropping the first line and `ID` and `query` columns after loading the whole file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can pass into `pandas.read_json` a file handler as well. If before that we read part of the data, then only the rest will be converted to `DataFrame`.

```
def read_json(file, skiprows=None):
    with open(file) as f:
        if skiprows:
            f.readlines(skiprows)
        df = pd.read_json(f, lines=True) 
    return df
```

Comment: I like the idea ! I was looking for a way to skip the first N rows without having to guess the number of bytes of a line, but this can easily be obtained by specifying an integer N in the function, and looping with `f.readlines(1)` N times before reading the file with pandas.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the lines in the file and skip the first n ones, then pass it to pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import json


with open('filename.json') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()[2:]

df_tmp = pd.DataFrame(lines)
df_tmp.columns = ['json_data']

df_tmp['json_data'].apply(json.loads)

df = pd.json_normalize(df_tmp['json_data'].apply(json.loads))
```